# How to Detach Firebase Database listener - Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a simple contact form in AngularFire2 that sends the user data to the Firebase Database:

```
<div id="formulario" class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" formControlName="name">
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" formControlName="email">
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" formControlName="telefone">
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Mensagem" formControlName="message"></textarea>      
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left" [disabled]="form.invalid">ENVIAR</button>
  </form>
```

```
onSubmit() {
    const {name, email, telefone, message} = this.form.value;
    const date = Date();
    let formRequest = { name, email, telefone, message, date };
    this.af.list('/messages').push(formRequest);
    this.form.reset();
}
```

But when the user submits the form, it gets a new connection in the database (2/100)

[image]

I don't want that, I just need that the user sends the data to the Database and when he submits it, the the connection ends.

Comment: add your htm and service code

Comment: I don't have a service is just a html and ts component

Comment: then add your htm, have your code communicate with firebase?

Comment: The html was added. The connection with the database is perfect, the data is being send, whatever I want to close de simultaneous connection when the user submits the form

Comment: let me clarify two things, submitted data shown in DATA(first tab) and if you are sending data from localhost to firebase i.e (1/100) and if you are connected from live url i.e(2/100) this is how many users are submitted data  to your firebase database